# How to check Dell PERC H710 RAID drive status

Tags: dell-perc

I want to confirm that both the drives in our system are correctly added to the RAID 1 array on the server. The RAID card is a Dell PERC H710 controller.

From the iDRAC interface, it shows one drive as "Online" and one drive as "Ready":

[image: iDRAC Physical Disks]

However, from the PERC H710 BIOS utility it shows both drives as "Online":

[image]

Why does the iDRAC status not show both drives as "Online"? This possibly implies that one of the drives is not active in the array, though the BIOS utility contradicts this.

Answer (score 2):

I'd defer to what you see in the PERC BIOS. That's what matters. 
Continue with your server build and go from there.

Comment: Would tend to agree with you. Still strange the iDRAC shows different info - surely it all comes from the same source?

Comment: The iDRAC is not the source of truth. Please load your OS and the relevant Dell agents and see if this changes.

Comment: Loads of experience w/ PERC here... Strongly agree w/ @ewwhite on deferring to the info in the BIOS when you see a conflict like this. OMSA may not be properly displaying this drive's status due to it being a non-Dell disk, or even outdated FW or OMSA version.